# Cast from string "[Date format]" to type , VB6 No Source code

Tags: vb.net, windows

Hello I have a old VB6 database program
It its a lot buggy!!!
One of the errors i get is :

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.InvalidCastException: Cast from string "28/02/2015" to type
>   'Date' is not valid.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DateType.FromString(String
>   Value, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DateType.FromString(String
>   Value)    at Jamms.frmBudgetMat.frmBudgetMat_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

I DO NOT have the source code to fix this and the date in Regional settings do not seem to effect the format of this app ,how can i fix this in windows,not the program

Can You help?

Comment: This is not Visual Basic 6, this is Visual Basic .NET.

Comment: Ok i found the error the 28/02/2015 format of my pc mismatched the 02/28/2015 format of the *.mdb, to fix i had to open the *.mdb with access, open every table then save ,the changes was done to all client PC's aswhell (all client PC's must now have the same format set in regional settings!).Just goes to show a little more work in you code now will be less of a headache for the ppl without the source 10 years later!#$